# How can I show the equality between two symbolic matrices?

Tags: matlab

I need to prove that formula with using symbolic elements : (A*B)^-1 = B^-1 * A^-1
I couldn't figure out what is the problem but matlab does not show that these two matrices are equal.
Here is my code:

```
syms a b c d
A = [a b ; c d];
B = [c a ; b d];
F = simplify(inv(A*B));
G = simplify(inv(B) * inv(A));
isequal(F,G)
```

The result is 0 as I said above. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `(A*B)⁻¹ = B⁻¹∗ A⁻¹` is true only if `A` and `B` are non-singular. It is not true in general

Comment: ah okay, I replaced second matrix's entrys with e f g h and it is worked. I really have no idea why. Thanks anyway :)